# Pick a color from a list, array not found in Android

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, android-background

In the app, I am developing, I have to choose a color based on a number from 0 to 4. I have decided to create an int-array in the colors.xml but it's not working. The kotlin code, is not able to access the array.

Colors.xml

```
    <color name="col_0">#8cb6ff</color>
    <color name="col_1">#faf3a2</color>
    <color name="col_2">#52b030</color>
    <color name="col_3">#44af22</color>
    <color name="col_4">#37ad15</color>

    <array name="listColors">
        <item>@color/col_0</item>
        <item>@color/col_1</item>
        <item>@color/col_2</item>
        <item>@color/col_3</item>
        <item>@color/col_4</item>
    </array>
```

I tried with `<integer-array>` and same result.

This is how I am access it:

```
    val colors = context.resources.getIntArray(R.array.listColors)
    setBackgroundColor(colors[value])
```

I keep getting an `unresolved reference` for listColors

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code working in fragments

```
val colors = context?.resources?.getIntArray(R.array.listColors)
```

Problem may be in the R . Check the imports correctly given R path